# How to print the pattern as a function in c

Tags: c, string, function

I am learning to code in c. I have compiled this code and trying to convert this pattern to a function, need help in storing this pattern in a variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char a[256];
    int len,m,i,j,k;

    printf("enter string \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]",a);
    len=strlen(a);
    m=len;

    for(i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        for(k=len; k>= len-i;k--)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

        for(j=i+1;j<len-1-i;j++)
        { 
            printf("%c",a[j]);
        }  
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

:

this is the actual output for string input- abcdefghijklmnop -

```
 bcdefghijklmno
  cdefghijklmn
   defghijklm
    efghijkl
     fghijk
      ghij
       hi
```

I'm trying to create a function which returns this pattern.

trying to make patterns like,

```
abcdefghijklmnop
 bcdefghijklmno
  cdefghijklmn
   defghijklm
    efghijkl
     fghijk
      ghij
       hi 
abcdefghijklmnop
 bcdefghijklmno
  cdefghijklmn
   defghijklm
    efghijkl
     fghijk
      ghij
       hi
```

Comment: What pattern are you trying to store?

Comment: By "to convert this pattern to a function" I understand you want to refactor this to be moved into a function. Correct? That would however seemingly contradict "storing this pattern in a variable".

Comment: By "I have compiled this code" you mean you wrote this code, correct? Because I do not see compiling being relevant for your question. Could you describe what the idea and goal of the shown code is? That would make moving it in to a function easier. Also pointing out which parts you do NOT want in the function, i.e. which is the "calling code" part which afterwards is still inside `main()`?

Comment: The goal of the code is to make the pyramid like pattern of a string by eliminating 1st and and last character. I want to use this as a function.

Comment: @Yunnosch: I believe that the edit by user "Lukas" was intended to improve revision 1 of the code, before user "Barmar" applied his edit in revision 2. However, the edit by user "Barmar" was probably applied before user "Lukas" was able to submit his edit proposal. Therefore, I believe that user "Lukas" deserves the points for the edit proposal. The only remaining change is that the indentation style was changed. I have therefore restored OP's original indentation style.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel I lost track of history. You might be right. Sorry if the edit proposal was more substantial than I realised. If it was I do not begrude the reputation reward. However, there are still cleanups missing, which all edits skipped.... Anybody, please do not do another indentation or code-formatting syntax edit without improving lack of punctuation, defluffing, etc...

Comment: So your goal is to create a function which can process a string `"####"` and turns it into `" ## "`. What do you want the function to do on the second run on that output string? "eliminate first and last char" is probably not what you want to do in that case. Please provide sample input and the desired output for at least three calls to the targeted function.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to incorporate the additional information from your "The goal ...". I tried, but realised that I cannot. The question body and the explaining comment can not be merged into one clear description. At least not by me. So you need to do that. Please also describe the purpose of the program separately from describing the refactoring you want to do. Show the pyramid pattern and explain that it is the current output and that it should still be the output after the desired refactoring. Show the content of the string in each step, that allows to deduce the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, i have made edits. Thanks

Comment: @ArjunSagar: I have fixed the formatting in your edit, but the question remains unclear. For example, in [revision 5 of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69445555/5), you distinguished clearly between intended output and actual output, but in the most recent edit, this has become unclear again. The first pattern is not labelled in any way, so it is unclear what it represents. Also, you don't seem to have addressed some of the previous comments.

Comment: `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` is worse than `gets()`.  Use `fgets()`.

Comment: @chux: I fuly agree that it is just as bad as `gets()`, but what makes it "worse"?

Comment: @AndreasWenzel 1) `scanf("%[^\n]",a);` leaves the `'\n'` in `stdin`. 2)  Consider if the input is `"\n"`, what is in `a` after then call?

Comment: @chux: Ah, yes, you are right. Good point.

Comment: Please explain what exactly you mean with `"convert this pattern to a function"`. That part of the question remains unclear. Do you want part of the work to be done inside a separate function?

Comment: when i call the function it should return this pattern of strings.

Comment: @ArjunSagar: What exactly do you mean by "return"? Do you mean "print"? Or should the function actually return something with the [`return`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/return) statement, for example an array of pointers to strings?

Comment: i mean, the function should print the pattern when its called.

Comment: @ArjunSagar: So you only call the function once and it prints the whole pattern at once? Or do you want to call the function several times, for example once for every line of the pattern?

Comment: @ArjunSagar: By the way, when responding directly to someone's comment, you should normally notify that person of your comment, by writing that person's name with the `@` symbol. Otherwise, they may not notice your comment. It is not necessary to write your name when commenting on your post, because you are the owner of the post. However, other people won't automatically get notified. See the section "replying in comments" on [this official help page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting)  for further information.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel Sorry and Thanks for pointing out. Noted.

Comment: @ArjunSagar: In the title of your question, you state that you want to "store a pattern of strings in a variable". This contradicts the information that you stated to me in your previous comments. In your comments, you stated that you simply want to print the pattern, and not "store" it. Therefore, please edit your question title to fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The following code will produce the required output. The pattern is printed by the function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void fun(char s[], int m)
{
    int len,i,j,k, n;

    len=strlen(s);

    for(n=1; n<=m; n++)
    {
        for(i=0;i<(int)(len/2)+1;i++)
        {
            if(len%2 == 1 || i != (int)(len/2))
            {
                for(k=len; k>=len-i+1; k--)
                {
                    printf(" ");
                }
            }

            for(j=i;j<len-i;j++)
            {
                printf("%c", s[j]);
            }

            if(i != j)
            {
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    char a[256];

    printf("enter string \n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", a);

    fun(a, 2);

    return 0;
}
```